# Client is sending request twice to server?

Tags: node.js, http, server

I am very new to servers and node. I created a very basic httpserver and trying to print number of connection on console. Below is the code for the same

```
var count = 0;
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    count++;
    console.log('Count' + count);
    response.end(count + '');
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

After three connection count value is incremented upto 6. Please let me know why there is a increment of 2 count for every http request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser is likely requesting other URLs such as a favicon.ico which is something many browsers will do in order to find a small icon that it can display as a representation of the site.

To defend against that, you can check `request.url` for a specific path and only apply your logic if the path is what you expect.

Here's one way you could do that:

```
var count = 0;
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){
    if (request.url === "/") {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        count++;
        console.log('Count' + count);
        response.end(count + '');
    } else {
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write("Content not found");
        response.end();
    }
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

Comment: Yes, it seems browser is requesting for "/" and "/favicon.ico". Can you please explain why it is doing so?

Comment: @tor - It is a browser convention to ask a site for a favicon.ico image that the browser can display to represent the site.  You can just check the `request.url` value and ignore anything that is not `"/"`.